# How can I restore deleted contacts from iPhone 4s?

Tags: iphone, contacts, data-recovery

My wife and I both have 4s models and we both downloaded iOS 7 and now we have all contacts (hers and mine) on both phones. I started to delete some of hers on my phone and it deleted the same contacts on her phone automatically. How can I restore her contacts?

Answer (score -1):

The deleted and lost iPhone contacts can be recovered in 2 ways: recover from iPhone directly or restore from iTunes backup copy.

Answer (score -2):

I was just looking to fix the same problem. All of a sudden my contacts were gone/empty.
Been lazy and never set up iCloud. So all these other suggestions weren't going to work.

What I ended up doing

- Double tap home button
- Hold down on an icon that appears on bottom of screen and close all running apps
- Tap home button again
- Power off your phone
- Turn phone back on
- Open contacts and they should be restored.

Hope this works for you and any one else with the same problem. I'm off to go back up my phone to a computer and the cloud.

Comment: This seems to be a solution to another problem than the one described in the question.